# Xamarin mvvmcross How to show 3 layered data structure in UITableView?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

There is a UITableView in touchview screen.
It shows a list of Car.
 
MyCarsViewModel contains `List<Car>` cars.
Car contains `List<Wheel> wheels`.
Wheel contains `List<Tyer> tyers`.
I have to show this 3 layered data structure in one tableview.
How can I achieve this?

Car1
|----Wheel1
     |------------tyer1
|------------tyer2
|----Wheel2
...
Car2
...

PS:
In android, it will be implemented 3 layered MvxLinearLayout.
   
So in main.xml

```
  <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listCars"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Cars" />
```

in listCars.xml

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listWheels"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Wheels" />
```

In listWeels.xml

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listTyers"
                        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Tyers" />
```

How can I implement this in xamarin.iOS?

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: i added output scheme.

Comment: How can a wheel have a multiple tires? Is the other tire a spare one? Or do you mean the wheel is an fact an axle and the tires are wheels and then the wheels have tires?

Comment: I'm still not sure what effect you are trying to achieve. Do you have a sketch of the UI? Or could you write the pseudo code for what you'd do on another platform - eg on windows in xaml?

Comment: Stuart, Cheesebaron, I added android code in PS part. could you advice for iOS implementation?

Comment: @stuart, could you help me?

Comment: @stuart, do you have any advice? Any advice will be appreciated.